# How to change loopback API response to a particular format

Tags: node.js, api, express, loopbackjs

I am new to loopback I want to change every response from my loopback remote method API to a particular format

eg: if success

```
{
    status:1,
    data:{},
    message:"Success"
}
```

If error

```
{
    status:0,
    data:{},
    message:"Something went wrong"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a boot script to change all remote method responses :

Create **hook.js** or any other name in **/server/boot/**

```
module.exports = function (app) {
var remotes = app.remotes();
// modify all returned values
remotes.after('**', function (ctx, next) {
    if (ctx) {
        ctx.result = {
            status: 1,
            data: ctx.result,
            message: "Success"
        };
    } else {
        var err = new Error();
        next({
            status: 0,
            data: err,
            message: "Something went wrong"
        });
    }
    next();
});
```

};

Check these links for more information :

**Formatting remote method responses (Last Section)**

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html

**Hooks**

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Strong-Remoting.html